# HTML Table: border-collapse and visibility collapse of tr

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a table with multiple lines, e.g.:

```
<table>
   <tr id="line1"><td>Line</td><td>1</td></tr>
   <tr id="line2"><td>Line</td><td>2</td></tr>
   <tr id="line3"><td>Line</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now, in javascript (based on a radio input field) I want to remove (e.g.) `#line3` by adding a `visibility:collapse`, something like:

```
document.getElementById("line3").style = "visibility:collapse";
```

The special thing about `#line3` is that it has a `border-top`:

```
<style>
   table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
   }
   #line3 {
     border-top:1px solid black;
   }
</style>
```

The problem I have with that: When I "collapse" `#line3` the border persists, eventhough the element "does not exist". I guess this should be due to the `border-collapse` in the table style "inheriting" a border element on the previous `tr` element? How can I fix that issue?

EDIT: I'd like to keep the javascript like that. Of course I could remove/readd the style element but there should be a different way to solve this?!

Comment: Please provide a code sample - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do not alter inline style, instead toggle a class, e.g. `#line3.hideme {
  border-top: none;
  visibility: collapse;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Of course I could remove/readd the style element

I think this means you don't want to mess with the `border-top` property when changing the row's visibility, correct?

In that case, it looks like your only option is to use `display:none` instead of `visibility:collapse`[1], which is unfortunate because then your table might have the wobbly effect that `visibility:collapse` was designed to prevent.

[1] https://drafts.csswg.org/css-tables-3/#visibility-collapse-track-rendering is not crystal clear, but looks like the spec prescribes the behavior you don't want. And chrome and firefox act a bit differently in the visibility:collapse case. https://jsfiddle.net/dgrogan/gLqo9s4w/2

```js
let visible = 1;
toggle.onclick = function() {
  line3.style.visibility = visible ? "collapse" : "visible";
//line3.style.display = visible ? "none" : "table-row";
  visible = !visible;
}
```

```css
   table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
   }

td {
  border: 1px solid lime;
}

   #line3 {
     border-top: 2px solid black;
   }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="line1">
    <td>Line</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="line2">
    <td>Line</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="line3">
    <td>Line</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br><br>
<button id=toggle>toggle</button>
<P>
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-tables-3/#visibility-collapse-track-rendering
</P>
```

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I guess I'll have to use `display:none` then. Well, this looks a bit like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "display: none"?

```
     document.getElementById("line3").style = "display: none";
```

Or maybe you could try setting the border-top to 0 which should hide it.

```
    document.getElementById("line3").style = "visibility:collapse; border-top: 0";
```

Comment: Thanks. I had hoped to be able to use the visibility:collapse without changing the border property.

Answer (score 1):

## [`.cssText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText)

You can edit the whole inline `[style]` attribute by using `.cssText`:

> ```
> document.getElementById("line3").style.cssText = "visibility:collapse; border-top:0px";
> ```

This allows you to set `visibility` and `border` properties (and more if you want) in one line.

---

### Demo

```js
document.getElementById("line3").style.cssText = "visibility:collapse; border-top:0px";
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#line3 {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="line1">
    <td>Line</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="line2">
    <td>Line</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="line3">
    <td>Line</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Comment: Thanks but I was more looking for a solution that doesn't need to change the border property.

Comment: Um, what do you mean when you said: *"The problem I have with that: When I "collapse" #line3 the border persists, eventhough the element "does not exist""*

Answer (score 0):

You have several solutions to do this, with Jquery:

```js
$('#line1').hide();

//OR

$('#line1').css('visibility','collapse');

//OR

$('#line1').css('display','none');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr id="line1"><td>Line</td><td>1</td></tr>
   <tr id="line2"><td>Line</td><td>2</td></tr>
   <tr id="line3"><td>Line</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can also use Javascript directly with the getElementById property:

```
document.getElementById("line1").style.display = "none";
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("line1").style.visibility = "collapse";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not answer my question. You ignored the style I defined for the table.